# Easy way to go to the definition of a function (Emacs, Ocaml)

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, ocaml

I am coding Ocaml under Emacs...

I would like to know if there is a shortcut to jump to the definition of a function (where the cursor is). At the moment, to do so I have to search the name of the function in the whole file, or look for `let the_name_of_the_function` and `let rec the_name_of_the_function` and `and the_name_of_the_function` which is obviously tedious...

By the way, I have alreay the file `.annot`.

Could anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: same here. I installed tuareg but nothing else explains how you can jump to definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My `ctags(1)` (from the `exuberant-ctags` package) supports the OCaml language and Emacs supports `ctags` when it is executed as `etags`.

So try: `cd /path/to/Ocaml/sources/ && etags -R .` to build an index, and then within `emacs`, <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd><kbd>ret</kbd> to search for the tag under the cursor.

Comment: Sorry, where should I run `etags -R .`?

Comment: Updated the answer: you need to run `etags -R .` from whichever directory has all your sources.

Comment: `etags -R .` under a terminal gives `etags: skipping .: it is not a regular file.`. I tried `etags -R file.ml`, no new file has been generated, and `M-.` under Emacs gives `[no match]`....

Comment: Hrm; I believe you have a different `etags` installed than I do. (`etags -R .` works without problems for me...) Check your `etags(1)` manual page to see how to run it correctly -- and if it will even work for you.

Comment: I have installed the newest `exuberant-ctags`, `etags -R .` works fine now, but no new files have been generated, is it normal? `M-.` under Emacs still gives `[no match]`...

Comment: If your cursor isn't on anything, then `M-. [tag]<ret>` should search for something you type...

Comment: Ok, now I have found `M-.`, then it shows `Find tag (default xxx)`, after pressing `RET`, it asks `Visit tag table (default TAGS):`, after pressiong `RET`, it shows `No tags containing xxx`. Where could I check if the tag table have been generated?

Comment: @SoftTimur The tags should be in the file called `TAGS` in the directory where you ran `etags`. You can look at its contents (it's human-readable, mostly).

Comment: Actually `exuberant-ctags` should be installed in this way: `sudo apt-get install exuberant-ctags`

Answer (score 4):

The problem could be solved with merlin (https://github.com/the-lambda-church/merlin). Merlin can be installed easily with opam:

```
opam install merlin
```

Follow the instructions provided by opam to configure ~/.emacs file. To finish the configuration you will have to provide a .merlin file that tells merlin where the source files and build files are located and which packages are used in the project. A brief overview of the .merlin file is given in https://github.com/the-lambda-church/merlin/wiki/emacs-from-scratch#configuring-your-project

Now, to jump to the function definition in Emacs:

```
C-c C-l
```

To move back to the function call:

```
C-c &
```

Answer (score 3):

While you are waiting for a better solution (of which there are some, see for example [OCamlSpotter](https://bitbucket.org/camlspotter/ocamlspot)) you can use the poor-man commands listed below. Assumes tuareg-mode.

```
(defun camldev-identifier-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (1+ (point)))
    (let* ((beg (re-search-backward "[^A-Za-z0-9_'][A-Za-z0-9_'`]"))
           (beg (1+ beg)))
      (goto-char (1+ beg))
      (let* ((end (re-search-forward "[^A-Za-z0-9_']"))
             (end (1- end)))
        (buffer-substring beg end)))))

(defun camldev-goto-def ()
  "Search for definition of word around point."
  (interactive)
  (let (goal (word (camldev-identifier-at-point)))
    (save-excursion
      (re-search-backward (concat "\\(let \\([^=]*[^A-Za-z0-9_']\\|\\)"
                                  word "\\([^A-Za-z0-9_'][^=]*\\|\\)=\\|"
                                  "fun \\([^-]*[^A-Za-z0-9_']\\|\\)"
                                  word "\\([^A-Za-z0-9_'][^-]*\\|\\)->\\|"
                                  "and \\([^=]*[^A-Za-z0-9_']\\|\\)"
                                  word "\\([^A-Za-z0-9_'][^=]*\\|\\)=\\)"
                                  ))
      (re-search-forward (concat "[^A-Za-z0-9_']" word "[^A-Za-z0-9_']"))
      (setq goal (1+ (match-beginning 0))))
    (push-mark)
    (goto-char goal)
    ))

(defun camldev-goto-spec ()
  "Search for specification in mli/ml file of word around point in ml/mli file."
  (interactive)
  (let* (goal
         (word (camldev-identifier-at-point))
         (search-expr (concat "\\(val [^:\n]*"
                              word "[^:]*:\\|"
                              "let [^=\n]*"
                              word "[^=]*=\\|"
                              "type [^=\n]*"
                              word "[^=]*=\\)"
                              )))
    (tuareg-find-alternate-file)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (re-search-forward search-expr)
      (setq goal (match-beginning 0)))
    (push-mark)
    (goto-char goal)
    ))

(define-key tuareg-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-d") 'camldev-goto-def)
(define-key tuareg-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-S-d") 'camldev-goto-spec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `otags` located here:
http://askra.de/software/otags/

From the project page:

> Otags generates TAGS files suitable for emacs and vi/vim from OCaml
>   sources. Otags employs camlp4 for parsing.

To use it, try something like:

```
otags -r src/
```

where `src` is the subdirectory containing your OCaml source files.
It should create a `TAGS` file.
Then you should be able to do `M-.` in Emacs.

You can install `otags` with `opam`.